# How does voltage fluctuation affect a laptop

Tags: voltage, laptop-repair

I own an Acer Aspire 3680. In the past 2 years, I have given, my laptop for service due to the same kind of problem. Last year at the same time, I gave my laptop to the service center. They repaired it and I managed to ask them this question: Why does this problem happen. How can I prevent it? They said, that due to voltage fluctuations, something has gone wrong in your laptop. They actually were hesistant in mentioning as to which part they changed/repaired. Now recently the same problem happened and again I gave it to a service center to get it repaired and they also said, this is caused due to voltage fluctuation.

> My Question is: Due to Voltage fluctuation which part of the laptop can get affected. How can I prevent this from happening.
>
> **Laptop Symptoms before I gave to service:** When I plug in the adapter for charging the **Green Light** blinks and the laptop doesn't turn on. Neither does the charging indicator indicates the light, while charging.

Comment: I think you should be wary of a laptop repairer who is reluctant to describe what exactly he did. You wouldn't tolerate *that* from a car repairer.

Answer (score 1):

"Voltage fluctuations" is the standard way of saying "I don't know what caused your problem" or "That component on this brand/model of computer fails all the time, and we just fix em --we don't try to understand the cause."

But since you seem to have a unit that is susceptible to this problem you should probably use a surge suppressor.  You may also want to think about replacing your power "brick", since it should be preventing "fluctuations" from reaching the unit itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in theory, your power supply should be the only thing that's directly exposed to the voltage fluctuations, and as a switching mode power supply, is supposed to be less susceptible to such issues.

Still, my best guess is, the power adaptor blew - if not that, the power circuitry on the main board (which means changing the whole main board).

Not actually having seen the laptop, what's the green light for? and where's the charging indicator? if the charging indicator is a light on the charger, probably means there's no power going in. the blinking green light COULD indicate critically low battery (especially with a beep) or.. well, nearly anything.

Comment: Well, you can see the image here: http://laptoping.com/wp-content/acer_aspire_3680-2682.JPG

Comment: The green light, in the adapter indicates, that it is charging.

Comment: hm, REALLY sounds like the adaptor, and the laptop just has flat batteries.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent this from happening.

You can purchase a power conditioner, the easiest way to do this is to buy an Uninteruptable Power Supply (UPS). Check the specific model, but most of these will regulate the output voltage when the input voltage goes too high or too low.

A cheaper option is a surge suppressor, but these usually need replacing after an over-voltage incident and do not really provide voltage regulation.